# Getting silent notification values when app starts

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement cache meachanism for FCM on IOS. I am using Xamarin Forms with  [CrossGeeks FirebasePushNotificationPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)

Push notification service works fine. I am using payload pattern as below

```
{
    "data": {
        "message" : "my_custom_value",
        "other_key" : true,
        "body":"test"
     },
     "notification": {
       "body" : "hello",
       "title": "firebase",
       "sound": "default",
        "content_available" : true
     },
     "priority": "high",
     "condition": "'general' in topics"
}
```

Above pattern appears delivered notification as alert on IOS main screen.

I have written a Dependency Service for getting undeleted or unopened accumulated notifications when app starts. Dependency Service include below codes

```
await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetDeliveredNotificationsAsync();
```

When I use above payload, I can get accumulated notifications. But when I use payload pattern as below, I can not.

```
{
    "data": {
        "message" : "my_custom_value",
        "other_key" : true,
        "body":"test"
     },
     "notification": {
        "content_available" : true
     },
     "priority": "high",
     "condition": "'general' in topics"
}
```

Actually I would like to send 2 payload types for every notification for my cache mechanism because of prevent the user's delete action. After that, I would like to show cached notifications without any lost in my app's notification page.

Shortly my question about "I am not getting silent payload values from `UNUserNotificationCenter` this approach is possible or not?"

Or can I prevent the user's notification delete action from IOS main screen when my app is terminated.

**Note:** My minimum OS version is 10.0 in info.plist

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would know if your payload is right when sending a silent notification? Because when I search the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification?language=objc), it says: `To perform a silent background update, specify the value 1 and don't include the alert, badge, or sound keys in your payload. `

Comment: Yes I have sent as you wrote. Without sound, badge and alert. But result is same. I would like to send duplicate notification. One of this silent other is alert. If user delete alert notification I would like to get silent payload values from UNUserNotificationCenter  next app open.

Comment: Does UNUserNotificationCenter  triggered when you send the notification? You can get the value there.

Comment: Accutally I do not now. But device console writes "Not delivering user visible notification 1CAA-B093 because it has no alert, sound or badge"

Comment: Other device log message is "Received remote notification request 7353-D49A [ hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 ]"

Comment: You can write some code in DidReceiveNotification to check if the app has received any message. You can read the document [Adding a notification content extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows#adding-a-notification-content-extension).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check soon.

Comment: Ok, you can share your solution here once you solved it:).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2024 update. Using FirebaseAdmin.Messaging and MAUI client ios and android.

Here is an example of what I am sending from the API. I am creating a message, adding to a list, then sending that list.

Helpful links
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/messaging/aps
https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#monitor-token-generation

```
// In my case I loop through a list
var messageList = new List<FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message>();
foreach (var what in ever) 
{
     var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
     {
          Token = firebaseToken,
          Notification = new Notification
          {
               Title = "New Message!",
               Body = "Message Here..."
          },
          Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
          {
               // Custom dictionary (works for both iOS and Android)
          },
          Apns = new ApnsConfig()
          {
               Aps = new Aps
               {
                    ContentAvailable = true, // For awaking app to run snippet
                    // Badge = trackingUserNotifications_InMyCase 
                    // Wish you could increment the badge but AFAIK you can't
                    // Comment out to not update the badge number
               }
          }
     }
     MessageList.Add(message)
}
// then send them all
await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAllAsync(messageList);
```

You can still use
`UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetDeliveredNotificationsAsync()` to get your notifications on iOS. Although now that I'm thinking about it ,for silent at least, you may need to run code that stores them in the notification center.